# HikariCP too many Connections with jooq due to that Hikari Cp Pool Initialisation Fail

Tags: jooq, hikaricp

I have service which is built in spring boot (2.4.5v) and its integrated with and jooq.  When we perform the load in our service we are getting too many connection with Jooq.

I am using the DSL context like this.

```
public class CourseRepository {
  @Autowired private DSLContext dslContext;
}
```

And I haven't provide explicit bean of DSLContext.

and Hikari CP configuration look like this,

```
spring.datasource.url=[My RDS URL]
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jooq.sql-dialect=MySQL
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.hikari.pool-name=[DB Name]
spring.datasource.hikari.initial-size=5
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=40
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=2
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=10000
spring.datasource.timeout=10000
```

Error Stack

```
error.class:java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException
error.message:Too many connections
error.stack: at
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110) at 
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMappi
ng.java:122) at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:833) 
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:453) at 
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246) at 
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) at 
com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) at 
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358) at 
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) at 
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477)
```

Another Error

```
error.class:org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException
error.message:jOOQ; SQL [Query]; Too many connections; nested exception is java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Too many connections
```

After reading several links and post, I found we have to provide the DSLContext bean,

```
 @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dslContext")
    public DSLContext dslContext(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        log.info("Datasource {}", dataSource);
        org.jooq.Configuration config = new DefaultConfiguration();
        config.set(dataSource);
        config.set(SQLDialect.MYSQL);
        return DSL.using(config);
    }
```

After adding these configuration ], I am getting different error.

```
error.class:org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException
error.message:Error getting connection from data source HikariDataSource (CorsairServiceDB)
error.stack: at org.jooq_3.13.2.MYSQL.debug(Unknown Source) at org.jooq.impl.DataSourceConnectionProvider.acquire(DataSourceConnectionProvider.java:86) at org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteContext.connection(DefaultExecuteContext.java:647) at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:334) at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetch(AbstractResultQuery.java:354) at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetchInto(AbstractResultQuery.java:1550) at org.jooq.impl.SelectImpl.fetchInto(SelectImpl.java:3746) at com.xyz.dao.CourseRepository.getCoursesByIds(CourseRepository.java:799) at com.xyz.dao.CourseRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b22a30cd.invoke(<generated>) at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
```

Comment: Check if you have any open `Cursor` or `Stream` objects in your code, which you didn't close as resourceful objects. I.e. look for all calls to `ResultQuery.fetchLazy()`, `ResultQuery.fetchStream()`, or `ResultQuery.stream()`

Comment: @LukasEder - I have provided the DSLContext  bean like this. ```@Primary
    @Bean(name = "dslContext")
    public DSLContext dslContext(DataSource dataSource) {
        org.jooq.Configuration config = new DefaultConfiguration();
        config.set(dataSource);
        config.set(SQLDialect.MYSQL);
        return DSL.using(config);
    }``` Will it helps to close the resourceful objects?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the information there? Also, that's not related to the concern I raised, have you checked what I was suggesting?

Comment: @LukasEder - thanks for your response I have checked we not using ResultQuery.fetchLazy(),  ResultQuery.fetchStream() and   ResultQuery.stream(), To test it out I have add the above configuration But after words. I'm not getting this too many connection.

Comment: But facing Different issue.  error.class:org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException
error.message:Error getting connection from data source HikariDataSource (CorsairServiceDB)